# How do you get all records from Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

How can I get all the records from the index using Sphinx? Just like a SELECT * FROM index ?
I know that I can do something like this in order to get all the records matching a specific keyword: /usr/local/sphinx/bin/search keyword, but what I want to do is to get all the records from the index.

Comment: are you using the command line "search" program or one of the APIs programmatically?

Comment: I'am using the php-based API, just used the command line as an example of what I'am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using an empty query or setting [the matching  mode](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#matching-modes) to SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN.

There isn't a way to do either of these things with the "search" command line utility but the test.py client that comes with the Sphinx source can be used for this:

`python ./sphinx-0.9.9-rc2/api/test.py -h localhost -i myindex`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an empty query. This worked for me with one of the releases.

Answer (score 0):

In sphinx.conf, doctype has to be extern